# Alignment in LinearLayout on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, alignment

I am a beginner at Android Studio and I am stuck with alignment now. I've looked around and searched but the solutions that I found didn't solve my problem or brought another problems.

My layout is like this:
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMdox.jpg)


Altitude:
10.0
Latitude:
latitudeTest
Longitude:
longitudeTest:
I need to place Altitude, Latitude and Longitude on the left and 10.0, latitudeTest and longitudeTeste on the right, kind of like this:


Altitude:                          10.0

Latitude:              latitudeTest

Longitude:        longitudeTest

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Altitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_altitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--10.0:-->
                android:text="@={``+waypoint.altitude}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lb_latitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Latitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_latitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lb_latitude"
                android:text="latitudeTest" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lb_longitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Longitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_longitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lb_longitude"
                android:text="longitudeTeste" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. You need to place the TextViews in different layouts to arrange their position. You'll get used to it, it is quite complex at first.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Altitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_altitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--10.0:-->
                android:text="@={``+waypoint.altitude}" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lb_latitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Latitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_latitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lb_latitude"
                android:text="latitudeTest" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lb_longitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Longitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_longitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lb_longitude"
                android:text="longitudeTeste" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout "A layout that arranges other views either horizontally in a single column or vertically in a single row." from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout)

In LinearLayout you only have a single column. If you want to have multiple elements next to each other in both directions use another Layout.